# iOS How to go to Previous to Previous View

Tags: ios, view, navigation, notifications

I have a situation where I want to go from Previous to Previous view. 
A MainView calls modal CWViewC calls modal CRViewC & that calls modal CRDViewC - on a action event in CRDViewC I need to return to CWViewC & update a component of it.

I want to use navigationController in my app, but am not able to set it, hence right now am not using it at all. I also am scared to play with Segue's also thinking that it might affect the compatibility of the app :(. I searched on net for similar situation but can't find a solution.

I could think of sending any sort of notification to CWViewc from CRDViewC. But again how to implement it in both respective classes & how to get rid of (I mean close) CRViewC then.

So please suggest and guide me for the same to solve the problem.

Any help is highly appreciated. Thanks.

EDIT :

My req was I have to call LoginVC prior & my main scrn is MAinTabVC. So I have made my app as TabbedTemplate & I call my LoginVC from AppDelgate & on when logged in successfully, from AppDelegate my MainTabVC comes up. This is how I call my login :

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
   // Override point for customization after application launch.

   // Get the StartupData properties from device
   MC_Utility *utility = [[MC_Utility alloc] init];
   self.theAppDataObject.startupData = [utility retrieveLocalData];
   NSLog(@"READ Loigin On Launch - %@",  self.theAppDataObject.startupData.loginOnLaunch);

   utility = nil;

   // Show Login view if not logged On
   if (!self.isLoggedIn) {
      [self showLoginScreen:NO];
   }

   return YES;
 }

 -(void) showLoginScreen:(BOOL)animated {
      // Get login screen from storyboard and present it
    UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main_iPhone" bundle:nil];
    LoginViewController *loginViewController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"loginViewController"];


    // Show Login
    if (theAppDataObject.startupData.loginOnLaunch.boolValue == true) {
        NSString *email = @"dylan@antila.co";
        NSString *pswd = @"t4Wzpg4OQ5q8ZNVDPPo7wg==";

        [loginViewController startLoginProcess:email :pswd];
     } else {
        [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
        [self.window.rootViewController presentViewController:loginViewController animated:animated completion:nil];
     }
}
```

Other all views that I normally show using such code :

```
    UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main_iPhone" bundle:nil];
MC_ChatWindowViewController *chatWindVC = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"chatWindowVC"];
[chatWindVC setModalPresentationStyle:UIModalPresentationFullScreen];
[self presentViewController:chatWindVC animated:YES completion:nil];
```

In my AppDelegate, I had tried to call mainTabVC, but wasn't successful. So stuck to original code. Tried several ways thru few tutorials also, but couldn't do it. I am a newbie in iOS development & am not finding comfortable yet to work with navControllers.

I have embedded NavController in LoginVC thru storyboard.

CODE Added in MAinTAB .m

```
@implementation MC_MainTabBarController

bool isLogged = false;

-(void) showLoginScreen:(BOOL)animated {
    NSLog(@"Calling Login from MainTab");
    // Get login screen from storyboard and present it
    UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main_iPhone" bundle:nil];
    LoginViewController *loginViewController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"loginViewController"];
    [loginViewController setModalPresentationStyle:UIModalPresentationFullScreen ];
    [self presentViewController:loginViewController animated:YES completion:nil];


    /* AUTO LOGIN
    // Show Login
    if (theAppDataObject.startupData.loginOnLaunch.boolValue == true) {
        NSString *email = @"dylan@antila.co";
        NSString *pswd = @"t4Wzpg4OQ5q8ZNVDPPo7wg==";

        [loginViewController startLoginProcess:email :pswd];
     } else {
        [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
         [self.window.rootViewController presentViewController:loginViewController animated:animated completion:nil];
     } */
 }
```

-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    if (isLogged == false) {
        [self showLoginScreen:YES];
    }

}

Comment: What do you mean by "am not able to set it" ? Is there a technical issue, or just a lack of motivation :p ?
In my opinion modal views should be used in very particular situation, for classic navigation you should go with a `UINavigationController`

Comment: @KIDdAe, In my first view i.e. LoginVC I embedded in NavContrl & I see NavigationItem in the story board in LoginVC. Earlier I have coded to navigate to all screens. In my Q. I have added code how I move from login to MainTabVC.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you mentioned segues, can I safely assume you're using storyboards? If so, get your first view controller (the one with MainView) in the storyboard file, go to the Product menu in the menu bar and select Embed In>Navigation Controller,as shown in this screenshot:

[image: How to embed a view controller in a navigation controller in Storyboards]

Then, change those segues between your view controllers to be Push rather than modal, so the one from mainView to the CWViewC will be Push, then the one from CWViewC  to CRViewC will be Push and so on.

The views won't be modal, but this is a much more natural way of progressing through a stack of views.

Comment: I have already Embedded my main view in navController - as I was expecting to have a navBar, but I failed to get navBar hence I left it as it is. And my all navigation happens thru code only & not segues. So haven't used segues once also.

Comment: Could you provide the code you're using in your original post?

Comment: Ok, thanks for the extra information. To clarify, you're using storyboards, and your loginVC is embedded in a navigation controller in the storyboard, but you're handling your navigation through code? If I've got that right, that sounds quite messy. I'd really recommend sticking to one or the other, so if you're using a navigation controller in your storyboard, stick to segues for the push navigation (You can do the other stuff in code, that's fine). Could you clarify? Thanks

Comment: yes absolutely right. Actually in early stage I was not willing to use NAvControl had in mind using that wouldn't be a good idea, so I had went thru code. Now, far in devlop of app, found that I need NavBar & for that need to add NavController. Also that its common & not at all bad to use NvCtrl in iOS. So embedded & try to show NavBar, but after spending 1 day after it couldn't get it, left it. Now in this situation, again found using NavCtr. My concern-fear want my app to be comptble with most version, & had read using NavC supports only 6 & +. Using Xcode 5 & my deploy is 6. U guide.

Comment: UINavigationController has been around since iOS 2.0, so you'll be fine. Plus, iOS 6 & iOS 7 combined make up for 97% of active devices, so its no problem. If you're going to use a navigation controller (which is often a good idea, it's a popular, useful and versatile way of handling navigation in an app) in a project using storyboards I'd stick to push segues in the storyboard - you can just change the current segues from Modal to Push.

Comment: Oh Thanks a lot. With this info & data you revealed me a big time tension. I was trying to get this type of info thru many sites, but was left confused/Not sure only. Thanks once again. Ok, so I have navCont in my app. At this moment is it possible to 1st just set the navi of the CWViewC, CRViewC & CRDViewC classes So app navigates thru that normally. I got to show the flow to someone, so asking. If not, then how to start to show Login prior to MainTab & on successful login dismiss login & MainTab appears.

Comment: Yes, that would be possible, but you'll need to make sure that process makes sense. You'll be handling the navigation through the storyboard, correct? I'd highly recommend following this guide up to the point "Adding Table View for Your Data" as it explains it really well. Please try this first, then I'll help with the rest. http://www.appcoda.com/use-storyboards-to-build-navigation-controller-and-table-view/

Comment: I have referred this tutorial many times & using this only I embedded NavContrl to my LoginVc. In my SB (storyboard) I also see relation bet NC & LoginVc. As that tut says that after this step on run I should see NavBar in my Login - I don't see that & am stuck at that place only. In my Login I also see "NavigationItem" which says that NC is linked with Login. Then why NB is not visible & then how to proceed.

Comment: Ok, MY app is a TabTemplate App, so MainTab is the InitialVC. BUT I want LoginVC to come prior to MainTab. First Login is shown as root view & then MAinTab is set as root view.  So I embedded in LoginVC - is that wrong ? Should I embed in MAinTabVC ?

Comment: So MainTab is/uses a UITabBarController? If so, that should really be the rootViewController at all times, and then I would suggest presenting the login view controller modally. So the InitialVC is root, and then in viewWillAppear in InitialVC you would do your check to see if the user is logged in. If not, present LoginVC modally, and this should show before the InitialVC is visible. Once the user has logged in then you would dismiss the loginVC, and they can then see the initialVC.

Comment: Also if you're using a tab bar controller (assuming you are with the Main Tab reference) then you'll have that be your root view controller, and for every tab you'll either have a UIViewController, or a UIViewController embedded in a UINavigationController if you want it to be able to push back and forth, and have a navigation bar. Example here: http://codingandcoffee.wordpress.com/2011/10/12/iphone-tutorial-two-combining-uitabbarcontrollers-uitableviews-and-uinavigationcontrollers/

Comment: Ok. I added a bool isLogged = false in MainTab.m - my initialVC. Have added code above in Q - pls chk. I expect Login scrn to be shown, but its not coming & straight MainTab is visible. In AppDelegate - I removed call to showLogin from  didFinishLaunchingWithOptions. So now, it just contains a call to retrieve data from NSUSerDefaults & retuers YES;

Comment: To add NAVContrl to MainTabVC - I removed the NC that was added in LoginVC. My every tab has a custom ViewController. >> or a UIViewController embedded in a UINavigationController - I didn't get this. Does this mean that I have to embed each & every VC in different NC ?? I am not able to embed NC in MainTab thru Editor menu. AS shown in tut I added NC from objects in my story board. I have 3 Tabs in my MainTab. In Storyboard, if I drag from MainTab to NC (as shown in tut) it creates a new Tab in MainTab. I don't want a new tab here. I want the existing to be hooked up.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/49235/discussion-between-mmo-and-tvd)

Comment: Thanks a lot. Your this guidance helped me a lot. It actually helped me understand an imp factor of NavController while I was misunderstanding even after reading several tutorials of it. U have given +1 to your every comment - as can't give more than once to your answer. Have other small concerns in respect to NC & view which will solve either thru finding on net or if required, ask other Q on the site. Thanks once again.

Comment: I'm so sorry, I didn't notice the questions you asked in the conversation yesterday - been very busy finishing off the week! So glad I was able to be of help :)

Comment: that's Ok dear. I also solved that "Two stage rotation" warning. Adding "[super viewDidAppear]; in viewDisAppear() of MainTab helped me solve that warning too. Now am all set with Navigation things.